# Woocommerce – if one of two product_ids is in cart at checkout, add form fields and show/hide divs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

That's pretty much it. My php-fu is still quite weak, and I'm still pretty new to woocommerce as well.

I need to create a script that checks for one of two specific product ids in the cart on the checkout page, and if one is there, add a "paypal email address" text field and a "receive-newsletter?" checkbox, as well as swap out a div I created in the "form-shipping.php" template with another, hidden div.

Surprisingly, my research so far hasn't turned up much in even just successfully confirming matching product_ids in the cart on the checkout page, which seems like it would be a reasonably common need. I'd consider that alone to be a huge victory at this point.

Any suggestions, guidance or clues on accomplishing this goal would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I've been working with, attempting to adapt from https://wordimpress.com/create-conditional-checkout-fields-woocommerce/:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'aym_custom_checkout_field' );

function aym_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

     //Check if Product in Cart
     $prod_in_cart_17563 = aym_is_conditional_product_in_cart_17563( 17563 );
     $prod_in_cart_17558 = aym_is_conditional_product_in_cart_17558( 17558 );

     if ( $prod_in_cart_17563 === true || $prod_in_cart_17558 === true ) {


        //Prod is in cart so hide div
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".checkout_promo_content").css("display", "none")</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".checkout_promo_aff_content").css("display", "block")</script>';

         //and add additional fields
         echo '<div id="email_paypal"><h3>' . __( 'Paypal Email Address' ) . '</h3><p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Please enter the email address you use for Paypal</p>';

         woocommerce_form_field( 'pp_email_textbox', array(
         'type'  => 'text',
         'class' => array( 'paypal-email form-row-wide' ),
         'label' => __( 'Paypal Email Address' ),
         ), $checkout->get_value( 'pp_email_textbox' ) );


         echo '<h3>' . __( 'Ambassador Terms and Conditions' ) . '</h3><p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Please accept the <a href="http://www.acceleratingyoungminds.com/ambassador-terms-conditions/">Ambassaor Terms and Conditions</a></p>';

         woocommerce_form_field( 'amb_terms_checkbox', array(
         'type'  => 'checkbox',
         'class' => array( 'amb_terms-checkbox form-row-wide' ),
         'label' => __( 'I accept Ambassador terms and Conditions' ),
         ), $checkout->get_value( 'amb_terms_checkbox' ) );


         echo '<h3>' . __( 'Subscribe for Ambassador Mailing List' ) . '</h3><p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Would you like to subscribe for welcome emails and important information</p>';

         woocommerce_form_field( 'amb_sub_checkbox', array(
         'type'  => 'checkbox',
         'class' => array( 'amb_sub_checkbox form-row-wide' ),
         'label' => __( 'I would like to subscribe to the Ambassador Newsletter' ),
         ), $checkout->get_value( 'amb_sub_checkbox' ) );

         echo '</div>';
     }

}


?>
```

Comment: Please, "__write/debug-my-code__", "__recommend/search-something-for-me__", "__tutorial__" requests and "__low-effort__", "__unclear__", "__opinion-based__", "**non-programming-related**" questions are [Off-Topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Good questions instead, as described in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), have **research effort**, a **clear explanation of the problem** and should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which version of woocommerce?

Comment: Version 2.6.14, but of course we will have to upgrade soon. Using a premium theme that has still not upgraded to accommodate 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rookie move, I failed to even define the functions for the two products (aym_is_conditional_product_in_cart_17563, etc). Secondly, I called JQuery incorrectly for Wordpress. Thirdly, I used the wrong hook in add_action. Fourthly, I initially posted this whole thing prematurely and in a rush. I have brought shame to my family. The following code works as expected. Hopefully it helps someone with a similar issue.

```
//AMBASSADOR CUSTOM CHECKOUT FIELDS, CONTENT
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'aym_custom_checkout_field' );

function aym_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

     //Check if Product in Cart
     $prod_in_cart_17563 = aym_is_conditional_product_in_cart_17563( 17563 );
     $prod_in_cart_17558 = aym_is_conditional_product_in_cart_17558( 17558 );

     if ( $prod_in_cart_17563 === true || $prod_in_cart_17558 === true ) {


        //Prod is in cart so hide div
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function($) { 
            $( window ).load(function(){
                console.log( "hidden!" );
                $(".check-promo-content").css("display", "none");
            });
        });

        </script>';

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            console.log( "shown!" );
            $(".checkout_promo_aff_content").css("display", "block");
        });</script>';

         //and add additional fields
         echo '<div id="email_paypal"><h3>' . __( 'Paypal Email Address' ) . '</h3><p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Please enter the email address you use for Paypal</p>';

         woocommerce_form_field( 'pp_email_textbox', array(
         'type'  => 'text',
         'class' => array( 'paypal-email form-row-wide' ),
         'label' => __( 'Paypal Email Address' ),
         ), $checkout->get_value( 'pp_email_textbox' ) );


         echo '<h3>' . __( 'Ambassador Terms and Conditions' ) . '</h3><p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Please accept the <a href="http://www.acceleratingyoungminds.com/ambassador-terms-conditions/">Ambassador Terms and Conditions</a></p>';

         woocommerce_form_field( 'amb_terms_checkbox', array(
         'type'  => 'checkbox',
         'class' => array( 'amb_terms-checkbox form-row-wide' ),
         'label' => __( 'I accept Ambassador terms and Conditions' ),
         ), $checkout->get_value( 'amb_terms_checkbox' ) );


         echo '<h3>' . __( 'Subscribe for Ambassador Mailing List' ) . '</h3><p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Would you like to subscribe for welcome emails and important information?</p>';

         woocommerce_form_field( 'amb_sub_checkbox', array(
         'type'  => 'checkbox',
         'class' => array( 'amb_sub_checkbox form-row-wide' ),
         'label' => __( 'I would like to subscribe to the Ambassador Newsletter' ),
         ), $checkout->get_value( 'amb_sub_checkbox' ) );

         echo '</div>';
     }

}
//TEAM LEADER BUNDLE
function aym_is_conditional_product_in_cart_17558( $product_id ) {
     //Check to see if user has product in cart
     global $woocommerce;

     //flag no product in cart
     $prod_in_cart_17558 = false;

     foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
         $_product = $values['data'];

         if ( $_product->id === $product_id ) {
             //product is in cart!
             $prod_in_cart_17558 = true;

         }
     }

     return $prod_in_cart_17558; 
}
//AMBSSADOR BUNDLE
function aym_is_conditional_product_in_cart_17563( $product_id ) {
 //Check to see if user has product in cart
 global $woocommerce;

 //flag no product in cart
 $prod_in_cart_17563 = false;

 foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
     $_product = $values['data'];

     if ( $_product->id === $product_id ) {
         //product is in cart!
         $prod_in_cart_17563 = true;

     }
 }

 return $prod_in_cart_17563;
```